# How can I log an Object in a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, logging, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on a project for a coding challenge and I don't know how to print an object in the Mongo schema below.

I need to know what the contents of the argument in `finishQuest()` are, but the script hardly gets called at all in the app. `console.log` gets blocked in testing, so that's a no-go and can't run node file.js, because it's using Node 6 and the file has imports. I've never worked in a file structure this large.

```
schema.methods._processBossQuest = async function processBossQuest 
(options) {
  let {
    user,
    progress,
  } = options;

  let group = this;
  let quest = questScrolls[group.quest.key];
  let down = progress.down * quest.boss.str; /* multiply by boss 
  strength */
  // Everyone takes damage
  let updates = {
    $inc: {'stats.hp': down},
  };

  group.quest.progress.hp -= progress.up;
  /* TODO Create a party preferred language option so emits like this 
  can be localized. Suggestion: Always display the English version 
  too. Or, if English is not displayed to the players, at least 
  include it in a new field in the chat object that's visible in the 
  database - essential for admins when troubleshooting quests!*/

  let playerAttack = `${user.profile.name} attacks 
  ${quest.boss.name('en')} for ${progress.up.toFixed(1)} damage.`;

  let bossAttack = CRON_SAFE_MODE || CRON_SEMI_SAFE_MODE ? 
  `${quest.boss.name('en')} does not attack, because it respects the 
  fact that there are some bugs\` \`post-maintenance and it doesn't 
  want to hurt anyone unfairly. It will continue its rampage soon!` : 
  `${quest.boss.name('en')} attacks party for 
  ${Math.abs(down).toFixed(1)} damage.`;

  /*TODO Consider putting the safe mode boss attack message in an ENV 
   var*/

  group.sendChat(`\`${playerAttack}\` \`${bossAttack}\``);

  /* If boss has Rage, increment Rage as well */
  if (quest.boss.rage) {
    group.quest.progress.rage += Math.abs(down);
  if (group.quest.progress.rage >= quest.boss.rage.value) {
    group.sendChat(quest.boss.rage.effect('en'));
    group.quest.progress.rage = 0;

  /* TODO To make Rage effects more expandable, let's turn these 
  into functions in quest.boss.rage */

      if (quest.boss.rage.healing) group.quest.progress.hp += 
        group.quest.progress.hp * quest.boss.rage.healing;
      if (group.quest.progress.hp > quest.boss.hp) 
        group.quest.progress.hp = quest.boss.hp;
      if (quest.boss.rage.mpDrain) {
        updates.$set = {'stats.mp': 0};
      }
    }
  }

  await User.update(
    {_id:
      {$in: this.getParticipatingQuestMembers()},
    },
    updates,
    {multi: true}
  ).exec();

  /* Apply changes the currently cronning user locally so we don't 
  have to reload it to get the updated state
  // TODO how to mark not modified? 
  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/1167
  // must be notModified or otherwise could overwrite future changes: 
  if the user is saved it'll save
  // the modified user.stats.hp but that must not happen as the hp 
  value has already been updated by the User.update above */

  if (down) user.stats.hp += down;

  // Boss slain, finish quest
  if (group.quest.progress.hp <= 0) {
    group.sendChat(`\`You defeated ${quest.boss.name('en')}! Questing 
    party members receive the rewards of victory.\``);

  // Participants: Grant rewards & achievements, finish quest
    await group.finishQuest(shared.content.quests[group.quest.key]);
  }

  return await group.save();
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? `console.log gets blocked in testing` and what testing framework are you using?

Comment: When I run the built in test suit (I believe Travis and Mocha), console.log throws a “no-console” error in linting.

Comment: That's a lot of code; can you simplify your question?

Comment: Since it's for testing purposes, you can modify the linting rule within your `.eslintrc` to `“no-console”: 0` which turns it to false that way your `console.log` would work. And by the way you need to clean up your code separate comments from actual code

Comment: @JohnnyHK I wish I could. I’m not even sure of how to phrase it. I need to be able to see the contents of objects in this script, but I can’t use console.log or util and run from the terminal. Honestly, I’m just having a difficult time phrasing this.

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo that’s awesome. I have the feeling that this is going to be an easy fix now. This has been a few days with many firsts - automated testing, Docker, repos of this size - and I’m honestly just getting confused at this point.